# Drupal 8 migrating json data with no array label

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm learning how to create migrations in D8.
However, I have this annoying issue where my migration is listed when I execute *drush migrate-status* but the **total** and **unprocessed** values are shown as **N/A**, shown below:

```
Group: JSON People (people)  Status  Total  Imported  Unprocessed  Last imported
 nodetest                     Idle    N/A    0         N/A
 people_data                  Idle    1000   0         1000
```

My json config is as follows:

```
id: nodetest
description:  Testing for a node migration
label:  Node Test
migration_group: people

source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: json
  urls:
    - 'http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=family'
  # path: 'http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=family'
  item_selector:  /
  # identifierDepth: 1
  ids:
    show:
      id:
        type: integer
  fields:
    -
      name: name
      label: Name of show
      selector: name

process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: page
  title: name

destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
```

I have been unable to figure out what the issue is some I get figures rather than the **N/A** output I'm currently getting.

Any help, please!

**UPDATE:**
I found I was incorrectly using **show** as the **item_selector**. Infact, the json from the api service does not have a "label" which refers to all the json objects, as shown below:
[image: the first of 10 json objects]

So, I remove item_selector from the yml data and I then get **10** instead of **N/A** in the total column of the **nodetest** migration.

**The problem now is I get `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() DataParserPluginBase.php:121 [warning]`** warnings (1 for each json object).

And, when I attempt to migrate, I get the following error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() DataParserPluginBase.php:121                                                                                                      [warning]
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() DataParserPluginBase.php:121                                                                                                      [warning]
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Drupal\migrate\Row::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in                                                        [error]
/var/www/d8/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/migrate/source/SourcePluginBase.php on line 357 in Drupal\migrate\Row->__construct() (line 101 of
/var/www/d8/core/modules/migrate/src/Row.php) #0 /var/www/d8/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/migrate/source/SourcePluginBase.php(357):
Drupal\migrate\Row->__construct(Array, NULL)
#1 /var/www/d8/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/migrate/source/SourcePluginBase.php(330): Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\source\SourcePluginBase->next()
#2 [internal function]: Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\source\SourcePluginBase->rewind()
#3 /var/www/d8/core/modules/migrate/src/MigrateExecutable.php(188): FilterIterator->rewind()
#4 /usr/local/share/drush/includes/drush.inc(721): Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutable->import()
#5 /usr/local/share/drush/includes/drush.inc(712): drush_call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/d8/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/migrate_tools.drush.inc(317): drush_op(Array)
#7 [internal function]: _drush_migrate_tools_execute_migration(Object(Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration), 'nodetest', Array)
#8 /var/www/d8/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/migrate_tools.drush.inc(272): array_walk(Array, '_drush_migrate_...', Array)
#9 /usr/local/share/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_migrate_tools_migrate_import('nodetest')
#10 /usr/local/share/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#11 /usr/local/share/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command('nodetest')
#12 /usr/local/share/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#13 /usr/local/share/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#14 /usr/local/share/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main()
#15 {main}.
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Drupal\migrate\Row::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/d8/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/migrate/source/SourcePluginBase.php on line 357 in /var/www/d8/core/modules/migrate/src/Row.php on line 101 #0 /var/www/d8/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/migrate/source/SourcePluginBase.php(357): Drupal\migrate\Row->__construct(Array, NULL)
#1 /var/www/d8/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/migrate/source/SourcePluginBase.php(330): Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\source\SourcePluginBase->next()
#2 [internal function]: Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\source\SourcePluginBase->rewind()
#3 /var/www/d8/core/modules/migrate/src/MigrateExecutable.php(188): FilterIterator->rewind()
#4 /usr/local/share/drush/includes/drush.inc(721): Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutable->import()
#5 /usr/local/share/drush/includes/drush.inc(712): drush_call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/d8/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/migrate_tools.drush.inc(317): drush_op(Array)
#7 [internal function]: _drush_migrate_tools_execute_migration(Object(Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration), 'nodetest', Array)
#8 /var/www/d8/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/migrate_tools.drush.inc(272): array_walk(Array, '_drush_migrate_...', Array)
#9 /usr/local/share/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_migrate_tools_migrate_import('nodetest')
#10 /usr/local/share/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#11 /usr/local/share/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command('nodetest')
#12 /usr/local/share/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#13 /usr/local/share/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#14 /usr/local/share/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main()
#15 {main}
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Drupal\migrate\Row::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/d8/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/migrate/source/SourcePluginBase.php on line 357 in Drupal\migrate\Row->__construct() (line 101 of /var/www/d8/core/modules/migrate/src/Row.php).
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but can you verify the `item_selector` is correct and returning items?

Comment: @Kevin: I wondered about that but it seems correct to me. Please visit the source:url to confirm.

Comment: @Kevin: After further consideration, I think you were right about the **item_selector**. I updated my question

Comment: I see what you mean, the results themselves have no wrapper to touch. Did you try just '/' for item selector?

Comment: @Kevin: I had tried everything but **/**. I have now tried tried it, I am getting 10 items **BUT** the migration fails with the following message: **Migration failed with source plugin exception: id is defined as a source ID but has no value.                                                                             [error]**

Comment: You haven't defined an id source, which looks like it would be /id. This property is important so Migrate knows what to track as the sourceid.

Comment: @Kevin: I defined ids:
    id:
      type: integer

but it did not correct the issue. Would you please point me at an example on how to define *id source*. I haven't been able to find documentation on the yml migration settings

Comment: Did you check the examples in the migrate_plus module?

Comment: @Kevin: I've been following the examples all along. I have **ids:
    id:
      type: integer** already defined in my yml as is in the examples

Comment: Yes but in your yml example above, you have not defined id as a field. Check the migrate_plus.migration.wine_role_json.yml to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source in your migration yaml should look more like this:

```
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: json
  urls:
    - 'http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=family'
  item_selector: /
  fields:
    -
      name: id
      label: "Field you want to be the source id"
      selector: path/to/id
    -
      name: name
      label: "Name of show"
      selector: name
  ids:
    id:
      type: integer
```

`ids` are picked from `fields`. In the yaml provided above, you are missing the `ids` definition and its field.

Comment: Thanks dude! That was extremely helpful